# Get length of string before Dot "."

Tags: vba, excel

How can I get the number of characters before a dot in a string in Excel (VBA)?

For example:

213123.2321321 would become 6 and 33.2312312 would be 2.

I need it to change how my code works, and I think this should be fairly easy to do.

More Info:

What I want to do is this:

- If I have 123.123, I want it to become 0.123123
- If it's 1.23123, I want it to become 0.0123123
- and if it´s 4 digits, 1111.123123, then 1.111123123

Comment: basic or visual basic? Look for your language of choice equivalent of IndexOf(".") ehich will return the position of the first period (.)

Comment: Should be Visual Basic i guess. Will search on that.

Comment: Visual Basic for Applications if you're doing this in an Excel macro.

Comment: yes that´s it magos.
Will try to check Split and IndexOf.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052337/substring-in-vba

Comment: Well solved it using InStr to get the position of ".", so it´s solved.
Will write the Answer later as i can´t right now ( 8 hour wait)

Comment: Given your last example, you should use floats and divide by 100, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Int` to get the integer part of a number and then use `Len` to count how many digits.

Practical example:

```
Function ChangeNumber(n As Double)
    Select Case VBA.Len(Int(n))
        Case 1: ChangeNumber = n / 100
        Case 2, 3, 4: ChangeNumber = n / 1000
        Case Is > 4: ChangeNumber = n / 10000
    End Select
End Function

Sub Test()
    Debug.Print ChangeNumber(123.123) //Prints 0.123123
    Debug.Print ChangeNumber(1.23123) //Prints 0.0123123
    Debug.Print ChangeNumber(1111.123123) //Prints 1.111123123
End Sub
```

You can amend the `Case` statement to suit your needs i.e. whether to divide by 100, 1000, 10000 or whatever you choose.